# Maximum/Minimum theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I make it pretty short:

How can one proof that if $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ compact and $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous then: if $f$ acquires 1 local maximum in $U$ then $f$ takes the minimum at the boundary of $U$.

I think this is pretty clear, but I can not strictly proof it :-(
Thanks

PS: If I'm missing any assumptions here, with which you could proof it, it would be also helpful.

PPS: Maybe I should put emphasis on the fact that f acquires only ONE extremum in the form of a maximum. Not a second minimum.

Thanks for the down votes btw, with lots of stuff like this isn't true but lacking a counterexample. I'm simply asking for a formal proof of this in my opinion obvious fact. But a counterexample would also suit and help me!

Comment: It's false.  Try polynomials on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Can you make a counterexample pls.

Comment: This is still very unclear. You start by saying "$1$ local maximum", and then later you "put emphasis" on "only ONE extremum". That's not emphasizing anything, it's _changing_ the hypotheses. Try to give a clear statement of exactly what you do mean...

Comment: That's what you say, but that was not how I ever meant the question to be.
Also do not take it personal, but the other statement would have been rediculously false...That's why I thought it's obvious what it is meant.

Comment: Why on earth would you think this is true?  If it is true for $f$ than it is not true for $-f$ as the roles of max/min are reverses and if $g\circ f$ can manipulate to practically anything you want.  This is obviously a false statement.

Comment: Does $-f$ contain a maximum if f contains one? Obviously not....Therefore the analogous statement would be: if $-f$ contains 1 extremum in the form of a minimum then the maximum is attained at the boundary.

Comment: Then what the hell is your statement?  You can't have two *contradictory* statements *both* be true for *all* functions. It seems to me, you yourself, just argued the statement is *false*.  Are you looking for *one* function where it *is* true, because it is clearly false most of the time.

Comment: So you are asking.  "How can I prove $x^4 \equiv 6 \mod 10$?"  We point out that "$3^4 \equiv 1 \mod 10$ so it is false".  And then you say, "I thought I was being clear.  We need $x^4 \equiv 6 \mod 10$".  Do you understand that if we com up with a case where it fails then that is a *counterexample* and that is a proof that it is *false*?

Comment: Look: I know what you try to tell me, but I really don't want to go into this rediculous discussion. Just look at Alejandro's answer then it might be clear to you what was meant.

Comment: Okay,  You need to make it clear that "having exactly one maximum" is a *CONDITION* and not the *CONCLUSION*.  That was not clear at all.

Comment: I will try to think of making these things more clear in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U=[-1,1]$ (which is a compact subset of $\mathbb R$) and $f(x)=x^3-x$, then $f$ has both its maximum and its minimum at points in $U^\circ$, not at the boundary (at $x_M=-\frac{\sqrt 3}3$ and $x_m=\frac{\sqrt 3}3$, respectively).

So your claim isn't true.

For a less trivial example in $\mathbb R^2$ you can take $U=[-1,1]\times[0,1]$ and $f(x,y)=(x^3-x)(y-y^2)$, which you can prove has a maximum at $\left(-\frac{\sqrt3}3,\frac12\right)$ and a minimum at $\left(\frac{\sqrt3}3,\frac12\right)$, both in the interior of $U$. (*)

(*) Actually, you can argue that both global maximum and minimum (whose existence is a consequence of Weierstrass' theorem) do not belong to the boundary of $U$, since it's easy to see that $f(x,y)=0$ if $(x,y)\in \partial U$. But $f$ takes both positive and negative values in $U$ since $y-y^2\ge0$ for $y\in [0,1]$ while $x^3-x$ can take any sign in $[-1,1]$ (which implies that the maximum value is positive and the minimum value is negative, so neither is reached in the boundary).

---

If your statement meant to be

> If $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ is compact and the only extreme of the continuous function $f\colon U\rightarrow \mathbb R$ on $U^\circ$ is a maximum, then $f$ reaches a minimum at $\partial U$.

this is just a consequence of Weierstrass' theorem and the fact that $U=U^\circ\cup\partial U$.

Since $f$ is continuous and $U$ is compact, it has to reach a minimum on $U$, which has to be in $\partial U$ if it is not in $U^\circ$ (the hypothesis of the maximum in the interior is irrelevant in fact).

Comment: I don't know what to do, but I thought it was clear. I pointed out that f acquires only 1 maximum. Not a second maximum and also not a second extremum in the form of a minimum.

Comment: When you say that there's no minimum but the minimum is attained at the boundary, do you actually mean there's no minimum in the interior of $U$? Otherwise, to say there's no minimum but there is one at the boundary is nonsense.

Comment: The point is that $f$ is constrained to some finite compact domain $U$. By no minimum I mean no local minimum as in $f'=0$ and $f''>0$. I just mean the minimal value is attained at the boundary.

Comment: "I pointed out that f acquires only 1 maximum. Not a second maximum"  So this *PROVES* the statement is *FALSE*, doesn't it.  It is simply *NOT* true for $f = x^3 - x$.  Becase $x^3 - 3$ *DOES* have a max and a min in U.

Comment: I see... remember that 'local minimum' does not mean $f'=0$ and $f''>0$. There is a local minimum at $x_0$ if there is a neighborhood of $x_0$ in which the global minimum is at $x_0$. If $f$ happens to be $C^2$ (continuous partial derivatives of second order) AND $x_0$ is an interior point of the domain, then you can assure that $f'(x_0)=0$ and $f''(x_0)\ge 0$ (or more generally that $\nabla f(x_0)=\vec 0$ and $Hf(x_0)$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: I added something to my answer, that might be what you are looking for. And I would really appreciate that we keep the tone of this conversation relaxed. Maybe it wasn't your intention, but this is feeling awkward.

Comment: Thanks @ Alejandro. That's what I was looking for. I knew there had to be some theorem for something basic like this.

So you are saying "remember that 'local minimum' does not mean $f'=0$ and $f''\geq0$". Why do you say this? Do you want to put emphasis on $f$ not necessarily being differentiable?

Comment: Not necessarily being differentiable, not necessarily being $C^2$ and also that local extrema can be in the boundary of the domain, in which case the conditions on derivatives do not necessarily hold even if $f$ is $C^2$.

Comment: Can I not always define a derivative coming from inside the domain?
Like: $f(x)=|x|$ for $x=[0,1]$. In $x=0$ I'm taking the right-side-derivative.

Comment: Yes, but even in that case it need not be 0 at the extrema. Consider $f\colon [0,1]$ given by $f(x)=x$. It has a minimum at $x=0$ and a maximum at $x=1$, but the derivative (lateral derivative) at those points equals 1.

Comment: Ah. I see... A neighborhood would still exist in a one-sided $\epsilon$-environment were the min/max at the boundary is also global within that environment, right?

Comment: Right. In a general setting, if $f$ is defined over $U$, you can think that there's no 'greater' set; just $U$. So $x$ belonging to a ball centered at $x_0$ with radius $\varepsilon$ means implicitly $\underline{x\in U}$ such that $d(x,x_0)<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth would this be true?

Let $U = [-5,5]\times [-5,5]\subset \mathbb R^2$ and let $f(x,y) = (x-5)(x+5)x(y-5)(y+5)y$.  This has *several* max and min.  (If my instinct is right $f(-\frac {\sqrt {3}}{3},-\frac {\sqrt {3}}{3})=f(\frac {\sqrt {3}}{3},\frac {\sqrt {3}}{3})$ are both  max and $f(\frac {\sqrt {3}}{3},-\frac {\sqrt {3}}{3}) =f(-\frac {\sqrt {3}}{3},\frac {\sqrt {3}}{3})$ are both min. At any rate, the border is $f\mapsto 0$ is neither max nor min.

Answer (score 0):

Your claim is wrong. Take the following graphical counter-example:

[image]